# Is the Axe as powerful as it seems?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

Having an item that can potentially defeat all locks seems to be counter to the natural flow of the game where the Investigators go from room to room following clues.

Once the Axe is found, the Investigators can go whereever they want, short-circuiting the whole adventure?

Is there errata for the Axe, or am I misunderstanding it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't auto defeat ALL locks. Only those described as Lock Puzzles on the Lock card but not wiring or rune puzzles for example.

Comment: Checked the card.  It appears we completely misunderstood it.  We had it countering all lock cards (and none of the puzzles).  Whoops!

Comment: Happy to help! I'm constantly getting things wrong! We just finished a game where we were using equipment card attacks completely wrong! 8)

Comment: Us too.  We just played the one game of M&M so far, but it was well received and I expect to be playing again soon.